# Nuxt-Mail - Unable to send email to dynamic recipients

Tags: vue.js, email, nuxt.js, nodemailer

I am trying to create an application where I need to send emails to contact as per what the user desire.

For example,

A user would enter a desired info to be sent and fills in a **TO** input box and would expect the email to be delivered to that address.

In my Nuxt.js file:

```
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
['nuxt-mail', {
  message: {
    cc: '<default email to be cc'd everytime>',
  },
  smtp: {
    secure: true,
    host: '****',
    port: '****',
    auth: {
      user: '****',
      pass: '****'
    },
  },
}],
```

],

-- The following info is added.

I invoke send email on user action as:

```
send() {
    console.log('Sending mail -- ')
    this.$mail.send({
      from: this.from,
      to: this.to,
      subject: 'Test Email',
      html: '<p>Hello World</p>'
    })
  }
```

--
But the email is sent only to the cc'd contact and not to the **TO** contact.

Please help. Any inputs would be valuable.

Thanks :D